# grep and expression with (*,*)

Tags: grep

I have included `write(*,*)` in a large project. Now I want to grep

```
grep -n 'write(*,*)' response.f
```

and got nothing found. Why are expressions with parenthesess not suitable for classical grep?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parentheses aren't the problem, but `*` is a regex metacharacter. Try `grep -nF` to *not* interpret as a regex:

```
grep -nF 'write(*,*)' response.f
```

Or, alternatively, escape:

```
grep -n 'write(\*,\*)' response.f
```

Your regex was interpreted as "zero or more `(`, then zero or more `,`, then `)`.